Bulk insert rasters into GPKG
I wonder if there is a way to bulk insert TIFF rasters into a geopackage using python or gdal, to increase write performance.
GDAL needs to open an SQLite connection per added raster file (subdataset, RASTER_TABLE), which prevents you from using a single transaction to insert multiple rasters.
Concurrency doesn't seem to work with gdal_translate (failed: database is locked ERROR 1: Raster table XXX not correctly initialized due to missing call to SetGeoTransform()).
Ex:
gdal_translate src_1.tiff dst.gpkg -of GPKG -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=src_1  <== creation
gdal_translate src_2.tiff dst.gpkg -of GPKG -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=src_2& <== parallel insertion attempt
gdal_translate src_3.tiff dst.gpkg -of GPKG -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=src_3&
gdal_translate src_4.tiff dst.gpkg -of GPKG -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=src_4&
gdal_translate src_5.tiff dst.gpkg -of GPKG -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=src_5&

GDAL's GPKG driver doesn't seem to support WAL mode.
